# Pourquoi l'ordre des mots a-t-il été changé dans cet extrait de l'Étranger? « un feutre mou à la calotte ronde »

Tags: sens, habillement

Il semble que le sens a été obscurci en disant cela au lieu de « ...**la calotte rond à un feutre mou** et aux ailes larges ». Y a-t-il une raison ou règle pour expliquer cet extrait? Peut-on généraliser cette règle?

> Il avait **un feutre mou à la calotte
>   ronde et aux ailes larges** (il l’a ôté quand la bière a passé la
>   porte), un costume dont le pantalon tire-bouchonnait sur les souliers*
>   et un nœud d’étoffe noire trop petit pour sa chemise à grand col
>   blanc. Ses lèvres tremblaient au-dessous d’un nez truffé de points
>   noirs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je comprends que la phrase puisse laisser pantois un non francophone à cause de la multiplicité des sens des mots *feutre* et *calotte* mais pour un francophone le sens est évident.

**[Feutre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/feutre)**  peut désigner plusieurs choses dont une matière (1) et un couvre-chef (3).

**[Calotte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/calotte)** peut désigner plusieurs choses dont un couvre-chef (1) et une forme (5), la calotte d'un chapeau, terme employé en chapellerie, c'est la partie supérieure du chapeau qui est juste au-dessus du sommet du crâne.

Dans la phrase de Camus il s'agit d'un chapeau en feutre dont la calotte est ronde et le bord large. Eût-il s'agit de ton interprétation on aurait eu « Il avait une calotte ronde *en* feutre (*en* introduisant une matière, on peut aussi employer *de*).

Je n'ai pas trouvé en ligne d'illustration exacte du feutre décrit par Camus, mais ce serait un peu comme un [Fedora](http://paulinechapeliere.com/modeles/) mais avec une calotte ronde au lieu de la calotte fendue du Fedora. Et certainement  avec un bord (« ailes ») plus large.

Answer (score 2):

Si je ne m'abuse (je ne suis pas spécialiste des chapeau), la *calotte* et les *ailes* sont des parties du chapeau en question. La formulation serait donc correcte.

Feutre (ou feutre mou, parfois avec un trait d'union) est en français un terme qui peut désigner les chapeaux de cette matière, notamment ceux ayant la forme d'un borsalino ou d'un fédora.